# Getting error "CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ReadJson'" when using foreach loop to read and display JSON file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Trying to iterate over JSON file using foreach loop statement but seem to be getting the below error
CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ReadJson' because 'ReadJson' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Get code here: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/y1Q1Cn

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;


public partial class ReadJson
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_xpath", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ItemXpath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_size")]
    public string ItemSize { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReadJson
{
    public static ReadJson FromJson(string json) { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadJson>(json, Converter.Settings); }
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this ReadJson self) { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings); }
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
    };
}

class UseJsonInVar
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string filepath = "Question__55692935.json";

        File.WriteAllText(filepath, GetJson());

        StreamReader ddd = new StreamReader(filepath);
        var json = ddd.ReadToEnd();
        var objectJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadJson>(json);

        foreach (var item in objectJson)
        {
            var url = objectJson.Items[0].Url;
            var user = objectJson.Items[0].ItemXpath;
            var pass = objectJson.Items[0].ItemSize;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}\n {2}", url, user, pass);
        }




    }

    static string GetJson()
    {
        var json = @"{
""items"":[
{
""url"":""https://www.nordstromrack.com/shop/Women/Clothing/Activewear/Jackets%20&%20Hoodies"",
""item_xpath"":""//*[@href='/shop/product/2299794/nike-vintage-drawstring-hoodie?color=BLACK%2FSAIL']"",
""item_size"":""//*[@href='?color=TRUBER%2FSAIL&size=L']""
},
{
""url"":""https://www.nordstromrack.com/events/281375/products/2584102/j-crew-cotton-cardigan?color=BLACK"",
""item_xpath"":""//*[@href='/events/281375/products/2584102/j-crew-cotton-cardigan?color=BLACK']"",
""item_size"":""//*[@href='?color=BLACK&size=M']""
}
]
}
";
        return json;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        try
        {
            UseJsonInVar.Test();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed with unhandled exception: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should be in the question, not just linked-to off-site.

Comment: You should iterate over the Items array not on the class containing the array

Comment: Alright I have added the code.

Comment: Can you remove the Down vote now that I have added the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't enumerate over `ReadJson` in a `foreach` because it doesn't implement the `GetEnumerator` method.

I think what you want to do is enumerate over `ReadJson`'s `Items` member like so:

```
var objectJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadJson>(json);
foreach (var item in objectJson.Items)
{
    var url = item.Url;
    var user = item.ItemXpath;
    var pass = item.ItemSize;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}\n {2}", url, user, pass);
}
```